# algebraic number $e^{\pi i /15}$

Tags: algebraic-numbers

How do I know that $$e^{\pi i /15}$$ is algebraic number? I know it is from the worlfram, but I don't know what method I can use to find if a number is algebraic.

Comment: It's a root of $x^{15}+1$.

Comment: It solves $z^{15}=-1$

Comment: Hint: Raise it to the power 15.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from knowing that $e^{i\pi} = -1$, it is possible to factor $i \pi$ as $15\frac{i \pi} {15}$, hence we have
$$ (e^{\frac{i \pi}{15}})^{15} = -1$$

Therefore it is possible to obtain this number by solving the polynomial $ z^{15} + 1 = 0 $.